# Propagating correlation-id not working

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I have the problem that the correlation-id is not propagated from my first to the my second microservice. I started to implement a servlet filter, a context and a context-holder as follows:

```
@Component
// Do not name bean "RequestContextFilter", otherwise filter will not work!
public class CallContextFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;CallContextHolder.getContext().setCorrelationId(httpServletRequest.getHeader(CallContext.CORRELATION_ID));

  filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, servletResponse);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
}
```

---

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
public class CallContext {
   public static final String CORRELATION_ID = "correlation-id";

   private String correlationId = new String();
}
```

---

```
 public class CallContextHolder {

private static final ThreadLocal<CallContext> userContext = new ThreadLocal<>();

public static final CallContext getContext() {
    CallContext context = userContext.get();

    if (context == null) {
        context = new CallContext();
        userContext.set(context);
    }
    return userContext.get();
}

}
```

Then, I implemented a RestTemplate bean as follows:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = template.getInterceptors();
    interceptors.add(new CallContextInterceptor());
    return template;
}
```

and the interceptor looks as follows:

```
public class CallContextInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
    headers.add(CallContext.CORRELATION_ID, CallContextHolder.getContext().getCorrelationId());

    return execution.execute(request, body);
}
}
```

When I call my endpoint, the servlet filter is executed and the correlation-id is stored in the CallContextHolder. So far, so good. However, the CallContextInterceptor seems to be called in an other thread and my ThreadLocal variable in the CallContextHolder is null. What I have to do to make this working?

```
@GetMapping("/ping")
public String ping() {
    return pongRestTemplateClient.getPong();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I'm using Hysterix. Hystrix spawns a new thread to execute the code, completely unaware of the "outer" thread context. So, the executing thread losses access to the ThreadLocal dependant functionality when using Hysterix commands.

I found an answer to my problem here: https://github.com/jmnarloch/hystrix-context-spring-boot-starter

Comment: Sleuth instruments Hystrix too. Basically copy what we did there cause I understand that you're redoing the same work

Comment: I'm going to try out Sleuth the next few days, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Spring Cloud Sleuth and just let the libary do the work for you? http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/spring-cloud-sleuth.html